# Difference between this.unblock and Meteor.defer?

Tags: meteor

In my methods, I use without difference alternatively `this.unblock` and `Meteor.defer`.

The idea, as I understand it, is to follow the good practice to let other method calls from the same client start running, without waiting for one single method to complete.

So is there a difference between them?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it will be easier to explain base on your code, so please include your code here

Comment: @Khang My question was rhetoric - no particular problem, just an hesitation on the best practice. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[this.unblock()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#DDPCommon-MethodInvocation-unblock)

- only runs on the server
- allows the next method call from the client to run *before* this call has finished. This is important because if you have a long running method you don't want it to block the UI until it finishes.

[Meteor.defer()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-defer)

- can run on either the server or the client
- basically says "run this code when there's no other code pending." It's similar to `Meteor.setTimeout(func, 0)`

If you deferred execution of a function on the server for example, it could still be running when the next method request came in and would block that request.

Comment: Does Meteor.defer affect other users and the overall event loop of the server? Or is it just the current client’s functions/events? Which is how I understand Meteor.unblock works.